# Character doesn't rotate back to his original position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following issue in my game;

When I shoot at my opponent I get his rotation in angle Y with the raycast hit, therefore I rotate my character in 90 degrees so I can shoot at him in a straight line as you can see in the code:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    if (hit.transform.tag == "Espantalho" || hit.transform.tag == "Xama" || hit.transform.tag == "Sheriff")
    {
        //instantiates the bullet
        GameObject tiro = Instantiate(projetil, SpawBala.transform.position, SpawBala.transform.rotation);
        Rigidbody BalaRigid = tiro.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        tiro.transform.LookAt(hit.transform.position);
        float AngleY = hit.collider.gameObject.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

        if (AngleY == 180 && !Girou)
        {
            player.transform.Rotate(0f, 90f, 0f);
            Girou = true;
        }

        if (Girou)
        {
            player.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 0f);
        }

        BalaRigid.velocity = SpawBala.transform.forward * ProjetilVeloc * Time.deltaTime;
        gameManager.PontoAcaop1--;
        Personagens[i].GetComponent<Jogador>().PodeAtacar = true;
        interfaceManager.ActionPointDown();
    }
}
```

However this condition isn't working, because my character doesn't rotate back to his original position. What have I done wrong guys?

```
if (Girou)
{
    player.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Is `0f` actually the original position? I'm not a Unity expert but it seems to me that `Rotate(0f, 0f, 0f)` would always rotate the player back to the same zero position (not whatever position they were at previously).

Comment: Try player.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);

Comment: @NateBarbettini It is man, I he rotates 90 degrees in Y angle, and then I'd like to rotate him back, after he shoots.

Comment: @ErikOverflow this way he doesn't even rotate 90 degrees ;/

Comment: `Rotate` actually rotates by the degrees that you provide. It doesn't change the rotation to the degrees you provide. This is basically the difference between addition and assignment. You are telling it to rotate 0 degrees, aka `dont rotate`.

Comment: @Josh thank you man, I didn't know that. Now, things are much more clear